# ReadAllBytesAsync(path) path always combined with the contentrootpath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, byte, webapi, virtual-directory

I want to return a files from virtual path directory, currently this is my code in C# asp net core.

```
     var path = GetConfig.AppSetting["VirtualDirectoryPath:PathLocal"] + "/" + 
                _.data.Downloadpath;
     var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
     if (!provider.TryGetContentType(path, out var contentType))
     {
         contentType = "application/octet-stream";
     }

     var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync("http://website.com/foldername/foldername/filename.pdf");

     return File(bytes, contentType, Path.GetFileName(path));
```

the DownloadPath contains 'foldername/filename.pdf', and the virtual directory path contains the localhost domain, i tried to hardcode the path but it keeps returning "D://folder/folder/http://website.com/foldername/foldername/filename.pdf". I don't know why the url combined with the contentrootpath, can someone help me?

Actually, i also want to retrieve a virtual directory path as url from the virtual directory that i already created in the iis so that i can download the files from the url. I don't know how to code better, if you can help me with this too i'd very much appreciate it. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the problem is that you seem to believe `File.ReadAllBytesAsync` downloads files from the web, it does not. It only reads files on your local file system.

And because `http://` files aren't supported, they're not considered to be [rooted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathrooted?view=net-6.0), and so it gets concatenated to the "current folder" and you get what you see.

Also never concatenate paths like that, that's what [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0) is for.